# Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babel

Добавил в свой проект `Truncate-react` после этого реакт попросил установить `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` что я и сделал в **package.json** файле таким способом

```js
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        {
          "loose": true
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
```

Разумеется сам `proposal-class-properties` я установил с меткой  **--save-dev**

но после всего этого мне все еще выбивает ошибку, которая выглядит так

[image: так]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно было поменять `import TextTruncate from 'react-text-truncate/src/TextTruncate'` на `import TextTruncate from 'react-text-truncate'` так как изначально я брал не скомпиленный файл и ловил ошибку